# Update SQL column if have duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-update

I'm trying to write a query  to update my table if any value appear more than one time. Example:

table:

| name | value | code | duplicated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jho | 10 | 81818 | false |
| Buo | 90 | 81808 | false |
| Jho | 10 | 81818 | false |
| May | 30 | 81898 | false |

Jho appear more than one time, so I want to set each of column as duplicated= true

table:

| name | value | code | duplicated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jho | 10 | 81818 | true |
| Buo | 90 | 81808 | false |
| Jho | 10 | 81818 | true |
| May | 30 | 81898 | false |

I tried subquery, but it don't work:

```
UPDATE table SET duplicated = true
FROM (SELECT name, COUNT(*) FROM table
      GROUP BY table.name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) as subquery
WHERE subquery.count > 1;
```

Any help on that?

Comment: A) It's better to be specific for which RDBMS you need solution: `UPDATE FROM` is very different in RDBMSs, b) in case of MySQL - it's better to specify version you're targeting (for postgresql too but not critical if it's  9.x or later) , c) [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) will help your question a lot

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.  Also explain what "don't work" means.  Is there an error?  If so what?  Does it do the wrong thing?  If so what?

Answer (score 1):

Using subquery for retrieving duplicate value then using JOIN for update duplicate column as true

```
-- PostgreSQL (v11)
UPDATE test
SET duplicate = true
FROM (
       SELECT name t_name
            , COUNT(name) total
       FROM test
       GROUP BY name
       HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
      ) t
WHERE name = t.t_name;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=92dfeb1b15d141e007fa49e61168e416

```
-- MySQL (5.6 to upper)
UPDATE test p
INNER JOIN (SELECT name t_name
                 , COUNT(name) total
            FROM test
            GROUP BY name
            HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
           ) t
       ON p.name = t.t_name
SET duplicate = true
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=d2571368bb55803276b4495cdff9a226

Comment: Welcome @FunnyDog. If it really help you please mark it accepted and also a upvote so that anyone can pick this without any doubt.